# Web Deploy 3, excluding assemblies (not PDBs)

Tags: webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Using Web Deploy 3, is there a way to exclude certain assemblies which a project depends on?

The scenario is:

1. Install the first package, platform-like assemblies.
2. Then we install product-like assemblies

Yes, I know that that we can use `–enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` flag to prevent the second package from overwriting the files.

I think it is just a bit dirty to have unwanted assemblies in the second ZIP package.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following switch

```
-skip:objectname='filePath',absolutepath='logs\\.*\\someNameToExclude\.txt'
```

to skip certain files when deploying from commandline (I used sync verb)

**Update**
As mentioned by msuhash - complete command-line reference can be found on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (see **skip** setting).

Comment: Yes, this works. Cheers. BTW for everyone's benefit  see this link for the documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd569089(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Glad it helped! Yeah, the command-line reference is very usefull as the syntax is not - emm - straightforward at least :)

Comment: I've added your link to the answr, so it is easy to find by anybody else